# SAS Variable with mixed values

Tags: date, sas, character

I have some variables that have date values however, some rows have character information thus making this a character variable. I need to add 90 and also subtract today's date from these variables. 
Example Variable
    **Variable1**
    08/30/18
    02/27/18
    06/30/18
    value
    05/31/18
    pending
    08/30/18

I was thinking, if there is a way to change all character values to missing/blank then I would be able to change this character variable to date format and do my calculations.

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a new date variable by "reading" your existing variable.

```
data mixed;
   input var:$8.;
   date = input(var,??mmddyy10.);
   if not missing(date) then do;
      p90 = date + 90;
      mtoday = date - today();
      end;
   format date p90 mtoday mmddyy10.;
   cards;
08/30/18
02/27/18
06/30/18
value
05/31/18
pending
08/30/18 
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: Thank you ! this worked but I am a bit confused what does '??' in front of  format -mmddyy10. mean?

Comment: @JCP the ?? is to suppress invalid data messages caused by the non date values of VAR.

Comment: You should be able to use it with any informat, perhaps 12 is just used too short a width, or there are non printing characters in the string.  Note there really isn't a `best` informat, SAS will just interpret that as a request for the normal `f` numeric informat. In some ways `comma` is the best informat since it can handle strings that include `$` and/or `,` characters.

Answer (score 0):

First You can test the syntax using one values. like this

```
  data _null_;
strdate='08/30/18';
a=input(strdate,mmddyy10.);
cal1=a+90-today();
cal2=put(cal1,mmddyy10.);
put strdate a cal1 cal2;
run;
```

Then create new variable for store new values, like cal2 above mentioned.

if you don't want to change original variable name, rename cal2 in data step.